# Saving a for loop result in a variable or saving it in a Gsheet

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-sheets

This is definitely a pretty basic question, but I can't seem to find a solution by myself, nor the answer in the depths of the internet.

Java script skill: **Newbie**

I am getting Google Forms Item Id's so that I could then edit/delete etc. even after somebody edits outside of my script.
To get them Ids I am using a 'for loop', which comfortably gets them for me in a string. Unfortunately I don't know how to save that result in a variable - always getting a syntax error.
I am also not happy with saving the logger.log in my google sheet.

Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
function GetItems3(){

    var formId = "your-id";
    var Form = FormApp.openById(formId);
    var ajtems = Form.getItems();


      for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++)
        {ajtems[i].getId().toString()
        Logger.log(ajtems[i].getId().toString())
        };
        //That saves the logger log in my sheet (DMsheet is a global var)
        var A = DMsheet.getRange(15, 6, ajtems.length, 1).setValue(A);}
```

Thanks in advanc3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong from your code.

1) There is no need to use the ***.toString()*** method because [getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getid) already returns the id as a String.

2) You didn't define your `ajtems` var.

3) You can't declare a var like `A` and use it at the same line you are declaring it because it hasn't been set yet.

4) You didn't declare `DMsheet`, this variable should contain your sheet and you would get it using the [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).

5) You said in your post "Java skill: Newbie". Java and JavaScript are not the same.

This code will help you to solve your issue:

```
function GetItems3(){
  var formId = "your-id";
  var Form = FormApp.openById(formId);
  var items = Form.getItems();
  // Get a sheet from the Spreadsheet you are running your script
  var dmSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  // Create an empty array to save the Form's items
  var myArray = [];
  for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    Logger.log(items[i].getId());
    // Sotre the title items in the array
    myArray.push(items[i].getTitle());
  };
  // Set the values in your sheet 
  dmSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, items.length).setValues([myArray]);
}
```

I really recommend you to take your time to read the [Apps Script docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). It will help you a lot to improve your coding and clear your doubts on how to use Apps Script in the best way possible.

Comment: Thanks for the array push resolution - it worked just fine
Also thanks for the extra materials -definitely will use them      

1) Logger.log showed weird huge numbers, and solution to use .toString() was taken from one of YT appscript tutorials - seemed to be working in Logger.log     
2/5) sorry, fixed it -my bad
3) It actually worked as intended in my code -setting values in spreadsheet
4) It is a global var, thats why it was not defined in this function